# Error 1191 - Basic Input Calculator in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to make a basic input calculator for class, but I am constantly encountering problems when I solve the old one.
Here is what I have so far:

```
var answer

import flash.events.MouseEvent;

plus.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,aaa);

function aaa(e:MouseEvent)
{
var a:Number = Number(input1.text) + Number(input2.text)

a.text = String(a);
}
```

The problem that I am having right now is 1119:Access of possibly undefined property undefined property text through a reference with static type Number

Answer (score 0):

For starters, the line you declare the variable `a` has no semicolon:

```
var a:Number = Number(input1.text) + Number(input2.text) // missing semicolon
```

Secondly, you define `a` to be a `Number`. The data type `Number` only has public methods and constants, not public variables, and none of its methods are `text`. Thus `a.text` gives you the error. [AS3 - Number Reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Number.html)

Thirdly, the `Number` data type has a method called `toString`. Therefore, simply call `a.toString()` instead of `String(a)`.

Lastly, if I knew what you were trying to do I would provide insight.

## Update

Try the following code out and let me know in the comments how it turns out.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent; // handle imports before anything else

var answer:String = ""; // holds the result of the addition as a String

// add a mouse click handler to the 'plus' object
plus.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, plusOnClick);

// 'plusOnClick' is the 'plus' object's mouse click handler
function plusOnClick(e:MouseEvent)
{
    // 'result' is used to hold the result of the addition as a Number
    var result:Number = Number(input1.text) + Number(input2.text)

    // set 'answer' to the String representation of 'result'
    answer = result.toString();

    trace("The result of the addition is " + answer);
}
```

Comment: I am trying to make a basic input calculator, where you put two numbers into two text boxes and press a button to calculate (add them together to start with) Thanks @JonnyHenly

Comment: @DylanI2000 check my update and see if that's what you're looking for, if not leave another comment explaining how it differs from your expectations.